# Need Help to Show Only these Lines of text in Php

Tags: php

I can't make my php code to show me all the lines that include the words: "Personaje" or "Cuadro de Dialogo" from a txt file that seems like this:

```
 seen 64
 images/mafalda_02_250_0.jpg: Predicted in 39.529000 milli-seconds. 
 Personaje: 100% 
 Cuadro de Dialogo: 99% 
 Cuadro de Dialogo: 98% 
 Personaje: 100%
```

the txt file is not static, and I need my php code to continuosly looking for those words and show the full line that contains them. I need my php code to show me something like this:

```
Personaje: 100%
Cuadro de Dialogo: 99%
Cuadro de Dialogo: 98%
Personaje: 100%
```

I've tried with this commands:

```
$lines = file('result.txt');
$lines = preg_grep("/Personaje:/", $lines);


foreach($lines as $name){
  echo "$name<br/>";
}
```

The problem is, when I have more than one result from "Personaje" or "Cuadro de Dialogo", it shows nothing.

Could someone help me pls?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, appears to work fine? https://3v4l.org/OlYZQ (using an array directly there, but that should made little difference over using `file`.)

Comment: Hi! it works fine when you have only one line of "Personaje" and "Cuadro de Dialogo". I need to be able to see all the lines that include those words, regardless the number of time they can appear. Hope it clarify ^^'

Comment: No it doesn’t; my example did contain _two_ “lines”, and it outputs them both. So, still unclear what the actual problem is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try Out using this example;

```
whitelist = ["home","dashboard","profile","group"];
$possibleUserInputs = ["homd","hom","ashboard","settings","group"];
foreach($possibleUserInputs as  $input)
{
     if(preg_grep("/^$input$/i",$whitelist)
    {
         echo $input." whitelisted";
    }else{
         echo $input." flawed";
    }

}
?>
```

this results in:
homd flawed
hom flawed
ashboard flawed
settings flawed
group whitelisted

**Hope this helps**

Comment: Hi! I've tried your code but it didn't work for what I'm looking for :/. Thanks for your time and help anyways ^^

Comment: Sorry About that, I thought it would guide you to get what you wanted. But If get some time i will look through it again and keep you posted. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**substr_count** is what you need

> substr_count: Count the number of substring occurrences

Example:

```
<?php
    $text = 'This is a Cuadro de Dialogo but not a Personaje, a Personaje is something else';

    echo substr_count($text, 'Personaje'); // prints 2

    echo substr_count($text, 'Cuadro de Dialogo'); // prints 1

    // if you need it case insensitive
    echo substr_count(strtoupper($text), strtoupper('Personaje'))

    // if you need to start from a certain point in the string
    echo substr_count($text, 'Cuadro de Dialogo', 30); //prints 0
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking your replying this post, but Substr_count will just count how many times those words appears right? I need php to show them on screen the lines that contains those words. Sorry if it was not clear enough what I'm looking for ^^'

Comment: What do you mean by lines? Does your text file break into lines? You can validate if the string is found more than 0 times in a certain line and then print that particular line, it's no big deal